# Maximum height of item in listview?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have this listview in my app that shows a chat. But at a certain point, the messages are getting cut like here:

[Listview with cutoff text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feGS2.png)

The text in the longer boxes is actually more, it just gets cut off.
I wrapped the text element inside a scrollview, so the user can actually scroll inside the message but id prefet it, if the whole text was shown.

It is as if the listview has a maximum row height?

Here is my view:

```
     <ListView  
                Margin="20,0,20,0"
                SeparatorVisibility="None"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                Refreshing="listview_AllChats_Refreshing"           
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                x:Name="listview_AllChats" >

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid Margin="0,15,0,15">


                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



                                <Grid Grid.Column="0" >
                                    <Frame 
                                         Grid.Column="0"      
                                         BackgroundColor="#00000000"
                                         WidthRequest="40"
                                         HeightRequest="40" 
                                         CornerRadius="{OnPlatform Android=60, iOS=47}"
                                         IsClippedToBounds="True"
                                         HasShadow="False" 
                                         Padding="0"
                                         VerticalOptions="Start" 
                                         HorizontalOptions="Start" >
                                        <Image
                                            x:Name="circle_profilepic" 
                                            Aspect="AspectFill"
                                            IsVisible="{Binding isMyMessage}"
                                            WidthRequest="500" 
                                            HeightRequest="500"
                                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                            Source="{Binding myUserPicture}">
                                        </Image>
                                    </Frame>

                                </Grid>

                                <Grid Grid.Column="1" >

                                    <Grid>

                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        
                                        <Frame BorderColor="#424242" HasShadow="False" CornerRadius="25"/>

                                        <ScrollView VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                                            <Label 
                                                Text="{Binding message}" 
                                                FontSize="15"
                                                Margin="25,1,25,0"
                                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                                FontFamily="Font_11"
                                                TextColor="#424242"
                                                />

                                        </ScrollView>
                                        <!--
                                              <Label 
                                                  Text="{Binding date}" 
                                                  FontSize="15"
                                                  Grid.Row="1"
                                                  VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                  HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                                  HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                                  FontFamily="Font_11"
                                                  TextColor="#424242"
                                                  />
                                        -->
                                    </Grid>
                                    
                                  
                                    


                                </Grid>

                                <Grid Grid.Column="2" >
                                    <Frame 
                                         Grid.Column="0"      
                                         BackgroundColor="#00000000"
                                         WidthRequest="40"
                                         HeightRequest="40" 
                                         CornerRadius="{OnPlatform Android=60, iOS=47}"
                                         IsClippedToBounds="True"
                                         HasShadow="False" 
                                         Padding="0"
                                         VerticalOptions="Start" 
                                         HorizontalOptions="End"  >
                                        <Image
                                            Aspect="AspectFill"
                                            IsVisible="{Binding isMyPatnersMessage}"
                                            WidthRequest="500" 
                                            HeightRequest="500"
                                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                            Source="{Binding myPartnerUserPicture}">
                                        </Image>
                                    </Frame>

                                </Grid>


                            </Grid>

                        </ViewCell>


                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

So how can I make it all be shown at once?

Comment: Check out this link: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From shared code, there are some unintelligible code may occur this phenomenon.

**First**, you are re-wrapping `Grid` inside root `Grid` layout, as follows:

```
<Grid Margin="0,15,0,15">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

         <Grid Grid.Column="0" > // here re-use Grid 
             <Frame Grid.Column="0"      
                    BackgroundColor="#00000000"
                    WidthRequest="40"
                    HeightRequest="40" 
                    CornerRadius="{OnPlatform Android=60, iOS=47}"
                    IsClippedToBounds="True"
                    HasShadow="False" 
                    Padding="0"
                    VerticalOptions="Start" 
                    HorizontalOptions="Start" >
           ...
```

**Second**, the `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` of image is larger then its container view(`Frame`).

```
<Grid Grid.Column="2">
    <Frame Grid.Column="0"
            BackgroundColor="#00000000"
            WidthRequest="40"
            HeightRequest="40"
            CornerRadius="{OnPlatform Android=60, iOS=47}"
            IsClippedToBounds="True"
            HasShadow="False"
            Padding="0"
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            HorizontalOptions="End">
        <Image Aspect="AspectFill"
                IsVisible="{Binding isMyPatnersMessage}"
                WidthRequest="500" // larger then 40
                HeightRequest="500" // larger then 40
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Source="{Binding myPartnerUserPicture}">
        </Image>
    </Frame>
```

**Therefore**, modify **xaml** code as follows to check:

```
<Grid Margin="0,15,0,15">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           
        <Frame Grid.Column="0"
                BackgroundColor="#00000000"
                WidthRequest="40"
                HeightRequest="40"
                CornerRadius="{OnPlatform Android=60, iOS=47}"
                IsClippedToBounds="True"
                HasShadow="False"
                Padding="0"
                VerticalOptions="Start"
                HorizontalOptions="Start">
            <Image x:Name="circle_profilepic"
                    Aspect="AspectFill"
                    WidthRequest="40"
                    HeightRequest="40"
                    IsVisible="{Binding isMyMessage}"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    Source="{Binding myUserPicture}">
            </Image>
        </Frame>

    <Frame Grid.Column="1"
            BorderColor="#424242"
            HasShadow="False"
            CornerRadius="25">

        <Label Text="{Binding Address}"
                FontSize="15"
                Margin="25,1,25,0"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                FontFamily="Font_11"
                TextColor="#424242" />
    </Frame>

        <Frame Grid.Column="2"
                BackgroundColor="#00000000"
                WidthRequest="40"
                HeightRequest="40"
                CornerRadius="{OnPlatform Android=60, iOS=47}"
                IsClippedToBounds="True"
                HasShadow="False"
                Padding="0"
                VerticalOptions="Start"
                HorizontalOptions="End">
            <Image Aspect="AspectFill"
                    WidthRequest="40"
                    HeightRequest="40"
                    IsVisible="{Binding isMyPatnersMessage}"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    Source="{Binding myPartnerUserPicture}">
            </Image>
        </Frame>

</Grid>
```

Here is the effect:

[image]